How to change the displayed column names in Flextable output?
I am attempting to change the displayed column names/labels after converting xtabs to flextable via set_header_labels. However, I run the following code and the labels do not change.
Here is what I tried:
library(flextable)
ft <- xtabs(~wool+tension, datasets::warpbreaks) |> as_flextable()
set_header_labels(ft, wool = "Type of Wool",Tension = "Tension Strength")

I was expecting to see "Wool" as "Type of Wool" but it remained as just "wool"

You can use labelizor() for replacement of labels:
library(flextable)
ft <- xtabs(~wool+tension, datasets::warpbreaks) |> as_flextable()
labelizor(ft, labels = c(wool = "Type of Wool",tension = "Tension Strength"),
          part = "header")



